# Set Maximum Size for Maximized Windows

Tags: gnome, 20.04, window-management, mutter

Is there a way to set the maximum allowed size for maximized windows?

Let me explain, I wish that the maximized windows do not cover the entire desktop, but I can set a margin or area to leave a part of the desktop visible.

For example:

[image]

I found a program that does exactly that but only for windows: [Change The Maximum Window Size - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/25/change-the-maximize-window-size/). I imagine there must be something similar for Linux but I can't find it.

Comment: I think you may achieve(workaround) it with a keyboard shortcut that sets the boundaries or rectangle with xy coordinates using wmctl or xdotool etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tests, solutions using commands and complicated scripts, etc, the best and simple solution that I found was using [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) widgets (yes, amazing); I found this solution accidentally while installing a widget I saw that all maximized windows are fixed to keep the widget in desktop visible.

The important part of the widget is "own_window_type panel" to create a window like a panel in your screen.

Then my solution was create a empty and transparent widget for each position of  screen when I need a margin(left, top, bottom, right)

**Left** widget example:

```
use_xft yes
xftfont 123:size=6
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0


double_buffer yes
minimum_size 10 1080
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color white
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color green
alignment top_left
gap_x 0
gap_y 1
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes
TEXT
```

All widgets are similar only changing size and the position in the screen.

This very simple solution works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

1. This can be done manually for [terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-terminal-sizes.html.en), [Vim](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size),[Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en).
2. You can use [xrandr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr) to get/set the screen resolution and then use [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) to resize your window

A bash script to resize windows to half their size with `wmctrl` is

```
#!/bin/bash
# resizes the window to full height and 50% width and moves into upper right corner

#define the height in px of the top system-bar:
TOPMARGIN=27

#sum in px of all horizontal borders:
RIGHTMARGIN=10

# get width of screen and height of screen
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(xwininfo -root | awk '$1=="Width:" {print $2}')
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(xwininfo -root | awk '$1=="Height:" {print $2}')

# new width and height
W=$(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - $RIGHTMARGIN ))
H=$(( $SCREEN_HEIGHT - 2 * $TOPMARGIN ))

# X, change to move left or right:

# moving to the right half of the screen:
X=$(( $SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 ))
# moving to the left:
#X=0; 

Y=$TOPMARGIN

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,$X,$Y,$W,$H
```

3. To move the windows, go to `Settings`, `Window Manager`, and click the `Shortcuts` tab. The actions you are looking for are named `Tile window to the left`, `Tile window to the top-right`, etc.
4. You can check out a GitHub Repo [here](https://github.com/gillesB/azulejo)

Hope this helps! Best of Luck ;)